# Prolog - Searching two lists for same element

Tags: prolog

I have a set of rules;

`family(Mother,Father,Children)` where children is a list, and `person/6`, I am trying to make two clauses, one to ensure a child can only be in one family, and the other if they're born on the same or consecutive dates then they need to be born in the same place.

```
bad_children(X) :-
    family(I,_,[J|T]),
    X = [J|T],
    person(J,_,_,_,date(E,_,A),place(C,_)),
    person(T,_,_,_,date(F,_,B),place(D,_)),
    E==F; E==(F+1); E==(F-1),
    C\==D,
    write(X).

bad_child(X) :-
    family(A,B,[H|T]),
    family(C,D,[Z|Q]),
    A\==C,
    B\==D,
    =(member(X,[H|T]), member(X,[Z|Q])),
    write(X).
```

My attemptds at each are above but neither work and I think i'm not on the right lines, can anyone give me any advice?

Comment: What is the intention of the expression `=(member(X,[H|T]), member(X,[Z|Q])`? In Prolog, this will attempt to unify the two terms, `member(X, [H|T])` and `member(X, [Z|Q])` which will succeed only if `X = X` (always will succeed of course), `H = Z` (`H` and `Z` can be unified) and `T = Q` (`T` and `Q` can be unified).

Answer (score 0):

Without a set of data is hard to test but... I suppose you could write

```
bad_children(X) :-
  family(_, _, X),
  member(J, X),
  member(T, X),
  person(J, _, _, _, date(E, M, Y), place(C, _)),
  person(T, _, _, _, date(F, M, Y), place(D, _)),
  (E is F; E is (F+1); E is (F-1)),
  C \== D,
  write(X).

bad_child(X) :-
  family(A, B, L1),
  family(C, D, L2),
  A \== C,
  B \== D,
  member(X, L1),
  member(X, L2),
  write(X).
```

A problem is that `bad_children()` return two times for every match: the fist for `J` and `T`, the second for the same children with reverse order.